# Using Laravel properly coming from non MVC PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am making an app and I am getting Laravel to do what I want but I think I am using it in the worst possible way.

I am doing things like this in views

```
<?php $array = explode(",", $comment->fields); ?>
@foreach ($array as $x)
<span class="post-tag">
{{ $x }}</span>
@endforeach
```

Should I do this in the controller? Or the Model? and how?

Comment: Can you move the `explode` into the `@foreach`, so as not to create an intermediate variable you don't need? If Laravel does not support that, do the explode in the controller instead.

Comment: Doing a foreach in your views is fine, but you want to keep the logic of exploding in a controller.

Comment: Laravel is a "non-MVC framework". It is another decedent of Rails.